# Powershell script. Modifying date from select statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is the current script we are using

```
import-module activedirectory

Get-Aduser -SearchBase "DC=XXXX,DC=LOCAL" -Properties * -Filter {employeeType -like "User"}  | 
    Select-Object givenname, sn, SAMAccountName, mail, idautoPersonEndDate, 
        idautoPersonBirthdate, employeeNumber, employeeType, 
        @{n='OU';e={($_.canonicalname -Split "/")[-4]}} | 
    export-csv "T:\IT\Techs\Userlists\destinystudents.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

what we are trying do get is the idautoPersonEndDate to be output something like this.

```
If idautoPersonEndDate <= today-60 then write "8-31-2013" else "do nothing"
```

the software we are importing the .csv file to requires a static date for that field and accounts stay active for a period of time before they are deleted.

The only way that i have been getting a start with this is

```
$today = Get-date
$today.ToShortDateString()

Get-Aduser -SearchBase "DC=XXXX,DC=LOCAL" -Properties * -Filter {employeeType -like "User"} |
Select-Object @{n={[idautoPersonEndDate]}
if ($n -le $today)
{
    "this"
}
ELSE
{
    "NULL"
}
```

I can be completely out to lunch on how i am thinking about this. So any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the information in a csv file in the end, so my sample below creates a CSV file. I hope you'll be able to use this to get what you want.

```
# faking data from active directory to make the sample possible to run without AD
$fakeDataFromActiveDirectory = @(
    New-OBject PSObject -Property @{ SamAccountName = "User1"; idautoPersonEndDate = (Get-Date 2012-01-01)};
    New-OBject PSObject -Property @{ SamAccountName = "User2"; idautoPersonEndDate = (Get-Date 2014-01-15)};
    New-OBject PSObject -Property @{ SamAccountName = "User3"; idautoPersonEndDate = (Get-Date 2013-12-20)};
    New-OBject PSObject -Property @{ SamAccountName = "User4"; idautoPersonEndDate = (Get-Date 2012-06-17)};
)

# using a fake "now" date, to make the sample runnable even in a couple of months
$now = Get-Date 2014-02-01
$maxAccountAge = New-TimeSpan -Days 60
$dateToCompareWith = $now - $maxAccountAge

# The "MyDateField" name can be named whatever you want your column to be named
# Also, the hashtable sent to the select statement can be shortened by using "N" and 
# "E" instead of "Name" and "Expression" if you want.
$dataWithConvertedDates = $fakeDataFromActiveDirectory | 
    Select SamAccountName, @{ Name = "MyDateField"; Expression = { 
            if ($_.idautopersonenddate -lt $dateToCompareWith)
            { 
                "8-31-2013"
            } 
            else 
            { 
                "do nothing" 
            } 
        } }

$dataWithConvertedDates | Export-Csv "C:\myoutput.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```